# How to make a css class work for only one object at a time?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

I want a css class to work for only one object at a time. I want to activate it only when I hover over an object with that class. When my cursor leaves that object the class should still be activated. But when I hover over a second object with that class it should simultaneously start working for that object and stop working for the previous object.

The css I am trying to implement this way is for a set of thumbnail images and is as follows

```
{
box-shadow: 0 0 5px red; 
}
```

None of the images should have this css activated by default when the page loads. How do I do it? Open to any kind of solution here css/javascript/jquery/plugin/anything elce. Can anyone help?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Answer (score 3):

Use `:hover`:

> The :hover CSS pseudo-class matches when the user designates an element with a pointing device, but does not necessarily activate it. It is generally triggered when the user hovers over an element with the cursor (mouse pointer).
>
> REF: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

```css
div:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<div>11111</div>
<div>22222</div>
<div>33333</div>
```

Solution 2: use `mouseover` event (or `hover` as @abeyaz's answer), remove all active then add the active class to the current one.

> The hover() function is more high level - it's built to call functions to handle both a mouseenter event and a mouseleave event. It's very convenient for a UI element that has a hover and normal state (e.g. a button.)
>
> The mouseover() function specifically binds to the mouseover event. It's best for situations where you only care when the mouse has crossed the border into an element and you don't really care what happens if it leaves. It's also the function to call when you want to trigger the event on some element.
>
> jQuery provides hover() as a convient way to handle common UI hovering states.
>
> mouseover() is more for manually accessing the specific browser event.
>
> REF: https://www.quora.com/jQuery/jQuery-What-is-the-difference-between-the-hover-and-mouseover-functions

```js
$('div').on('mouseover', function(){
  $('div').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
})
```

```css
.active {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>11111</div>
<div>22222</div>
<div>33333</div>
```

Comment: wrong answer the css  does not remain any when I stop hovering a div before i hover another. are u new to stackoverflow? u cant just post childish answers

Comment: @AsifAli ok, how about the 2nd solution

Comment: It doesnt remove the shadow on mouseout

Comment: @abeyaz hm, not sure about the requirement, small update. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily using jquery as in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4f1g1yxf/. You can do it easily using jquery as in fiddle below. The idea is simple; remove the class from activated one first, then add to the new one.

```js
$(".box").hover(function(){
 $(".box.activated").removeClass("activated");
 $(this).addClass("activated");
});
```

```css
.activated {
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px red; 
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">box1</div>
<div class="box">box2</div>
<div class="box">box3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach:

CSS:

```
.abc {
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px red; 
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
<p>hello</p><br>
```

JS:

```
jQuery('*')
    .bind('mouseover', function (event) {
        var o = jQuery(this);
        if (!o.find('.abc').length) {
            o.addClass('abc');
        }
    })
    .bind('mouseout', function () {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('abc');        
    });
```

P.S. Instead of '*' put the proper class or element identifier to limit event scope.

Comment: ignore previous one forgot to connect to jquery in it check this one https://jsfiddle.net/7xn6khym/

Comment: malfunctioning a bit

Comment: I've updated the main comment. First vision is not always the best one %)